# If $d|n$, then $\phi(d)|\phi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Where $\phi(n)$ denotes Euler's Totient Function. My proof follows, I was hoping someone could verify it, and give critique.

Let $d,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ so that $d|n$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, $n$ can be written in the following way:
$$n = p_1^{\beta_1}\cdots p_n^{\beta_n}$$
where $p_j,\ j=1,...,n$ are all distinct primes. As $d$ divides $n$, $d$ can be written as:
$$d=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$$
where $0\leq\alpha_j\leq\beta_j$, and $\ j=1,...,n$.
Then, using the multiplicative property of $\phi(n)$ and the fact that $\phi(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$:
\begin{align}
\notag \phi(n) &= \phi(p_1^{\beta_1}\cdots p_n^{\beta_n})\\
\notag &= \phi(p_1^{\beta_1})\cdots\phi(p_n^{\beta_n})\\
\notag &= p_1^{\beta_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdots p_n^{\beta_n-1}(p_n-1)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\notag \phi(d) &= \phi(p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n})\\
\notag &= \phi(p_1^{\alpha_1})\cdots\phi(p_n^{\alpha_n})\\
\notag &= p_1^{\alpha_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n-1}(p_n-1)
\end{align}
As $\alpha_j\leq\beta_j$ for all $j$, we must also have $\alpha_j-1\leq\beta_j-1$ for all $j$, and:
$$p_j^{\beta_j-1}(p_j-1) = p_j^{\beta_j-\alpha_j}p^{\alpha_j-1}(p_j-1),\ \forall j\in\{1,...,n\}$$
So $\phi(n)$ can be written as:
\begin{align}
\notag \phi(n) &= p_1^{\beta_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdots p_n^{\beta_n-1}(p_n-1)\\
\notag &= p_1^{\beta_1-\alpha_1}p_1^{\alpha_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdots p_n^{\beta_n-\alpha_n}p_n^{\alpha_n-1}(p_n-1)\\
\notag &= (p_1^{\beta_1-\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\beta_n-\alpha_n})p_1^{\alpha_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n-1}(p_n-1)\\
\notag &= (p_1^{\beta_1-\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\beta_n-\alpha_n})\phi(d).
\end{align}
and $\phi(d)|\phi(n)$.

Comment: It looks correct!! I think everything is right!!

Comment: It looks fine...a little long, perhaps.

Comment: Ha, I agree, I'll review your approach. Thanks!

Comment: A simple argument: the onto ring map $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/d\Bbb Z$ induces an onto homomorphism of unit groups. (This requires basics of abstract algebra.)

Comment: @seaturtles I'm not that familiar with rings yet, but I will definitely keep that in mind when I get there. Thanks!

Comment: @chs21259: When you have deduced the expressions for $\phi(d)$ and $\phi(n)$ you could easily claim that $\phi(d)$ $|$ $\phi(n)$ because $\beta_i \geq \alpha_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: @WilliamHilbert That shortens it up quite a bit, I didn't want to jump too many steps ahead, but I guess it is pretty obvious. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: First, you say $n = p_1^{\alpha_1}\dots p_n^{\alpha_n}$. This should rather be

$$n = p_1^{\alpha_1}\dots p_m^{\alpha_m}$$

as there is no reason to believe that the prime decomposition contains precisely $n$ primes.

Comment: Not that you care anymore after 5 years, but just posting this comment for future readers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints for a shorter and simpler, imo, approach:

Use that

$$n=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i}\;,\;\;p_i\;\;\text{primes}\;\;,\;\;a_i\in\Bbb N\implies \phi(n)=n\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)$$

so now

$$d\mid n\implies n= xd\;,\;\;x\in\Bbb N\implies\;\ldots$$